# migrating existing Azure VMs to Azure Premium Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

i am having two VM'S which is under domain running erp application and database server. Both vm are in Standard D12 v2 (4 cores, 28 GB memory)template.
Now we need to move these VM's into premium disk. So How can i migrate existing Azure VMs to Azure Premium Storage.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend migrating to Managed Disk and you can migrate existing VMs using standard storage account to Managed Disk and Premium Storage account follow article below.

[Migrate existing Azure VMs using standard unmanaged disks to Premium managed disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-unmanaged-to-managed-disks#migrate-existing-azure-vms-using-standard-unmanaged-disks-to-premium-managed-disks)

Answer (score 0):

We can migrate existing Azure VMs from standard storage account to Premium storage account, but we need to **shutdown** the VMs.

If we can shutdown the VMs, then we can follow those steps to migrate them:
1.Via Azure portal to **create a premium storage account**(new).
2.Shutdown Azure VMs, **copy VHDs** to premium storage account. we can use PowerShell, Azure storage explorer or Azcopy to copy VHDs to new storage account.
3.**Just delete Azure VMs** and keep the VHDs, Virtual Network, NIC, Public IP address and other settings.
4. **Use new storage account to create new VMs**, when we create new VMs, in the configure page, we select original Vnet and NIC to it.
5. After it complete, try to login those VMs and test 
erp application, **make sure that the VMs to run properly**, then delete original VHDs and storage account.

**Note**:
When we use VHDs from new storage account to create VMs, we need to select **VM disk type** to **SSD**.

===========================================
**Update**:
1. **stop** Azure VM and **delete** the VM via Azure portal.
2. use **Azcopy**(Microsoft Azure storage command line) to copy VHD to new Azure premium storage account:

```
AzCopy /Source:https://vmdisks416.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /Dest:https://jasondisk999.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /SourceKey:key /DestKey:key /Pattern:jasonvm20170519131021.vhd
```

3. Use PowerShell to **create** new Azure VM:

```
PS C:\Users> $rgname = "vm"
PS C:\Users> $loc = "eastus"
PS C:\Users> $vmsize = "Standard_DS1_v2"
PS C:\Users> $vmname = "jason-newtest2"
PS C:\Users> $vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmname -VMSize $vmsize
PS C:\Users> $nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name "jasonvm422" -ResourceGroupName $rgname
PS C:\Users> $nicId = $nic.Id
PS C:\Users> $vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nicId
PS C:\Users> $osDiskName = "jason-newtest"
PS C:\Users> $osDiskVhdUri = "https://jasondisk999.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/jasonvm20170519131021.vhd"
PS C:\Users> $vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -VhdUri $osDiskVhdUri -name $osDiskName -CreateOption attach -Linux
PS C:\Users> New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $loc -VM $vm
WARNING: Since the VM is created using premium storage, existing standard storage account, vmdiag614, is used for boot diagnostics.

RequestId IsSuccessStatusCode StatusCode ReasonPhrase
--------- ------------------- ---------- ------------
                         True         OK OK
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Comment: Does this helpful? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: I am following the above steps and let you know once its worked.

Comment: I have doubt that Existing VM's are under domain. Do i need to take any precaution steps before migrating those vm's

Comment: We use VHD to create the new VM, the new VM will join the domain by default, same as your original VM.

Comment: Yes thanks, i also used VHD. i ve migrated vhd to premium but i am getting following error while creating New VM. New VM is created but not able to login. This is Error: "New-AzureRMVM : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'.
ErrorCode: VMAgentStatusCommunicationError
ErrorMessage: VM 'myserver' has not reported status for VM agent or extensions. Please verify the VM has a running VM agent, and can establish outbound 
connections to Azure storage."

Comment: It seems like that your original VM have not delete, please make sure you have delete the VM, then try again. I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: @KarthickSundaram Does it helpful? Please let me know if you would like further assistance. If it helps, please don't forget to accept it, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am deleted VM again and followed the same steps but got same Error.    Uploaded the error with screenshot

Comment: New-AzureRMVM : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'.
ErrorCode: VMAgentStatusCommunicationError
ErrorMessage: VM '****' has not reported status for VM agent or extensions. Please verify the VM has a running VM agent, and can establish outbound connections to Azure storage.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Locati . + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand

Comment: Please try your original VHD to create a VM, does the same error? how do you copy VHD to new storage account?

Comment: In boot diagnostics - VM is in boot mode asking to " Please insert USB drive having bit locker encryption key"  - But there is no VM dISK Encryption enabled and No bitlocker enabled for any drive ; i am using Powershell to copy VHD , azcopy is not worked for me

Comment: Have you use azure key vault?

Comment: I have used azure key vault when VM disk encryption was enabled, but now i removed disk encryption in VM level and Drive level also. Dont know why it is asking for encryption key.  Finally i have restored the VM into old state from VM bakup. vm is up.. But i want to migrate to premium storage..

Comment: Have you try to use Azure backup to restore backed up disks, like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms#choosing-a-vm-restore-configuration, after that copy this VHD to new Azure premium storage account, then follow those steps to create new VM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-automation#create-a-vm-from-restored-disks